# Como enviar array Json do Jquery para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Tenho uma tabela onde constantemente as linhas mudam de ordem, preciso gravar essa tabela no banco. A partir do momento que não irei mais modificar a tabela eu clico em um botão "Confirmar Grid", nesse momento salvo essa tabela em um array dentro do jquery, e quando eu quiser mandar pro php clico para submeter no formulario.

Porém não consigo receber estes dados no back, recebo um "Notice: Undefined index: pilotos"

**html:**

```
    <table id="tabelaPilotos" class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
      {foreach from=$pilotos item=row}                        
           <tr>            
             <td>
               {$row.numero}
             </td>
             <td>
             {$row.nome}
            </td>   
            </tr>
    {/foreach}
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Confirmar Grid" >
    <form name="form_insert" method="post" id="form_insert">
       <fieldset style="display: none;"></fieldset>
       <label>
           <input type="submit" id="confirmar" name="confirmar" value="Cadastrar grid" />
    </label>
    </form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
    var pilotos = [];

$("#add").click(function () {
    $('#tabelaPilotos tbody tr').each(function () {
        var colunas = $(this).children();
        var piloto = {
            'numero': $(colunas[0]).text(), 
            'nome': $(colunas[1]).text()
        };
        pilotos.push(piloto);
    });
    console.info(pilotos[0]);
});

$("#form_insert").submit(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: pilotos,
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'cad_corrida.php',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });

});
```

**php:**

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       $pilotosarray = $_POST["pilotos"];
       echo "<script>alert('$pilotosarray')</script>";
     }
```

Como recuperar este array?

Comment: Isso que você está tentando fazer não existe, não dá pra enviar um echo de alert através do PHP, quando se usa smarty, a saída é enviada através de um array compilado que gera uma template de visualização desse compilamento, o que será visto é enviado numa view através de um elemento chamando `$smarty->assign('variavel', $dados)`. Observe que pelo layout da sua view isso é [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Aqui tem a [documentação do smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/)

Comment: Eu só usei este echo para testar se estava recebendo informações do front. Ele na verdade não me interessa.

Comment: É preciso colocar o código correto então do PHP, para que alguém possa te ajudar nisso. Porque me parece muito incompleta sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Para receber a informação no post como "pilotos" é preciso passar o índice e valor no data do ajax, é importante no back-end utilizar o **"isset($_POST['pilotos'])"**, para verificar se realmente há um índice com valor sendo recebido, e tratar o possível warning.

Caso o retorno do back não seja em formato JSON é necessário alterar o **"dataType"**, de acordo com o retorno esperado.

```
$("#form_insert").submit(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        **data: { pilotos: pilotos}**,
        **dataType: "ValorRetorno"**,
        url: 'cad_corrida.php',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Quando faço a verificação isset($_POST['pilotos']), ele não entra no if.

Oque seria o "ValorRetorno"?

Comment: O fato dele não acessar o isset é exatamente pq o indice ['pilotos'] está vindo com valor vazio, pra debugar isso coloque antes do if : 
echo "<pre>";
die(var_dump($_POST));

Answer (score 0):

O conteúdo que é enviado ao servidor vai no *corpo* da requisição. Ou seja, você pode lê-lo assim:

```
$conteudo = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Pode-se também usar a constante `STDIN`, que equivale a `php://input`:

```
$conteudo = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

Depois basta transformar esse conteúdo em um array:

```
$conteudo = json_decode($conteudo, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel,

Voce pode usar o JSON.stringify no javascript pra poder transformar seu objeto em uma string e passa essa string no seu "data" do ajax e no PHP você usa a função json_decode pra transformar de volta essa string em um array/objeto.

Não testei com código, mas teoricamente essa idéia funciona.

Referência:

> JSON.stringify:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
>
> json_decode: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Espero que ajude.

Vlw